# Does Priority support webhooks?

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I am writing a service that integrates Priority with another application. I would like to know if Priority has webhooks or a similar mechanism that would allow my service to be notified when there are changes to entities in Priority. 
E.g. when a new customer is created in Priority, my service would like to be notified.

Otherwise what would be your recommended approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are no webhooks support in Priority.
In Priority version 20.0, using [REST API](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/), You can retrieve data that have been modified since a certain date. Using [$since](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/query/#Retrieving_Only_Records_With_Changes)

> Rest API Release Notes (Priority V. 20.0)
>   Rest API Changes
>   Reworked text form support. Text will no longer be broken down into lines.
>   Documents (forms with Business Process Management) now support the use of $since to easily retrieve records that have changed since a given point in time.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Priority can be programmed to do a lot of stuff.

In this case you need to build a customize trigger that will send a notification (json/xml/plain text) to your web service when new customer is created.

It is Proirty programming and not PriorityWebSDK programming: The trigger should be written inside Priority.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 20.1 Priority supports webhooks for the BPM enabled forms.

To define one, first of all you need to create a record in the specialized form at `System Management > System Maintenance > Periodic Maintenance > BPM Maintenance > Webhook Definitions`.

Then you can use your previously defined webhook in the Business Rule Generator in very similar to SMS/email sending way.

This functionality isn't a part of the basic Priority package and you will need to buy dedicated module in order to enable it.